# Android Datepicker change text view Text when value changed

Tags: android, date, if-statement, numbers, numberpicker

I have a datepicker which has value of between 1-9 when the user scrolls to 1 I want it to say Night and the remaining 8 to change the text view to night. Currently my application just jumps to the last if statement and I can't seem to figure out why, it probably a small problem but I can't see it, could some one please spot my error?

Global Variables

```
NumberPicker numberOfDaysPicker;
int datepicker;
```

Oncreate

```
    numberOfDaysPicker.setMaxValue(9);
    numberOfDaysPicker.setMinValue(1);
    numberOfDaysPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
    datepicker = numberOfDaysPicker.getValue();


numberOfDaysPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {


          if (datepicker == 1) {

              nights.setText("Night");

          } else if (datepicker < 1) {

              nights.setText("Day");


          }
      }



  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
if (picker.getValue() == 1) {

    nights.setText("Night");

} else if (picker.getValue() > 1) {

    nights.setText("Day");

}
```

The value returned from `picker` will give you the changed value.

I also changed the else if to `>` so that any other number will be changed to "Day"